# Using Recursion to Find Permutations of Composite Laminate

Tags: algorithm, vba, recursion, permutation

I'm trying to make a subroutine in VBA that'll return all possible permutations of various angles from two inputs. First input is how many lamina (or layers) there are while the second is by what value will any individual lamina iterate. Each lamina has a max/min angle of 90/0 degrees. An example is shown below.

I have 5 lamina. I want the program to use a step of 45deg on lamina 1 (3 steps), a step of 30deg on lamina 2 (4 steps), a step of 15deg on lamina 3 (7 steps), a step of 10deg on lamina 4 (10 steps), and a step of 5deg on lamina 5 (19 steps). The program will return 1) the total number of permutations and 2) all possible permutations.

Right now I've got a subroutine in place that creates an 1D array of the same length as the lamina count that contains each step for its respective lamina. This array is passed to a recursive function that is **supposed** to perform the actual iterations. I already have a termination condition in place, so the function ends when I need it to end.

I need help with the mathematical side of this, and how to set up a recursive loop (because I'm assuming that'd be the only way to set up a dynamic nested loop). I'm pretty experienced in VBA, but have done very little with recursion. Thank you all in advance for your help.

The formula for the permutations in this situation is n!/(a_1!a_2!...a_k!), right?

Here's the code. I've bolded the parts that are relevant to my question.

```
Private Sub Finish_Click()

On Error GoTo ERROR_HANDLING
Dim SubName As String
SubName = "Finish_Click()"

Dim PD As Worksheet, ELP As Worksheet, OP As Worksheet
Dim LoopCount As Integer, i As Integer, SpaceLoc As Integer, StrLen As Integer, Number As Integer, CurrentPly As Integer, StepValue As Integer, PD_LR As Integer
Dim Permutations As Long, LoopSteps() As Long
Dim TitleRange As Range

Set OP = Worksheets("Laminate Optimization")
Set PD = Worksheets("Properties & Dimensions")
Set ELP = Worksheets("Properties & Dimensions")
LoopCount = PD.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Value / 2
Permutations = Opti_Parameters.Opti_Permutations.Controls("Permutation_Value").Value
CurrentPly = 0
PD_LR = PD.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row

ReDim LoopSteps(1 To LoopCount) As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For i = 1 To LoopCount
    If Opti_Parameters.Opti_Lamina.Controls("Control_" & i + (i - 1)).List(Opti_Parameters.Opti_Lamina.Controls("Control_" & i + (i - 1)).ListIndex) <> "" And Opti_Parameters.Opti_Lamina.Controls("Control_" & i + (i - 1)).List(Opti_Parameters.Opti_Lamina.Controls("Control_" & i + (i - 1)).ListIndex) <> "Static" Then
        SpaceLoc = InStr(Opti_Parameters.Opti_Lamina.Controls("Control_" & i + (i - 1)).List(Opti_Parameters.Opti_Lamina.Controls("Control_" & i + (i - 1)).ListIndex), " ")
        StrLen = Len(Opti_Parameters.Opti_Lamina.Controls("Control_" & i + (i - 1)).List(Opti_Parameters.Opti_Lamina.Controls("Control_" & i + (i - 1)).ListIndex))
        Number = Right(Opti_Parameters.Opti_Lamina.Controls("Control_" & i + (i - 1)).List(Opti_Parameters.Opti_Lamina.Controls("Control_" & i + (i - 1)).ListIndex), StrLen - SpaceLoc)
        LoopSteps(i) = Number
    End If
    OP.Cells(1, 5 + i) = "Angle " & i
    OP.Cells(1, 5 + i).ColumnWidth = 8
    OP.Cells(1, 5 + i).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    OP.Cells(1, 5 + i).NumberFormat = "#,##0"
    OP.Cells(1, 5 + i).Interior.Pattern = xlSolid
    OP.Cells(1, 5 + i).Interior.PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    OP.Cells(1, 5 + i).Interior.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
    OP.Cells(1, 5 + i).Interior.TintAndShade = -0.249977111117893
    OP.Cells(1, 5 + i).Interior.PatternTintAndShade = 0
    OP.Cells(1, 5 + i).Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous
    OP.Cells(1, 5 + i).Borders(xlEdgeBottom).ColorIndex = 0
    OP.Cells(1, 5 + i).Borders(xlEdgeBottom).TintAndShade = 0
    OP.Cells(1, 5 + i).Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Weight = xlThin
    OP.Cells(1, 5 + i).Font.Bold = True
Next i

OP.Cells(1, LoopCount + 6) = "Torsional Stiffness"
OP.Cells(1, LoopCount + 7) = "Critical Speed"
OP.Cells(1, LoopCount + 8) = "Buckling Torque"
Set TitleRange = OP.Range(OP.Cells(1, LoopCount + 6), OP.Cells(1, LoopCount + 8))
With TitleRange
    .Interior.Pattern = xlSolid
    .Interior.PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Interior.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
    .Interior.TintAndShade = -0.249977111117893
    .Interior.PatternTintAndShade = 0
    .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).ColorIndex = 0
    .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).TintAndShade = 0
    .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Weight = xlThin
    .Font.Bold = True
    .ColumnWidth = 20
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    .NumberFormat = "#,##0.00"
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

ReDim OriginalAngles(5 To PD_LR) As Integer
For x = 5 To PD_LR
    OriginalAngles(x) = PD.Range("D" & x)
Next x

**Call NestedLoop(PD, ELP, Permutations, CurrentPly, LoopSteps, OriginalAngles)**

Exit Sub
ERROR_HANDLING:
    MsgBox "Error encountered in " & SubName & ": exiting subroutine." _
    & vbNewLine _
    & vbNewLine & "Error description: " & Err.Description _
    & vbNewLine & "Error number: " & Err.Number, vbCritical, Title:="Error!"
    End

End Sub
```

Recursive Function:

```
Function NestedLoop(PD As Worksheet, ELP As Worksheet, Permutations As Long, CurrentPly As Integer, LoopSteps() As Long, OriginalAngles() As Integer) As Integer

On Error GoTo ERROR_HANDLING
Dim SubName As String
SubName = "NestedLoop()"

If CurrentPly > UBound(LoopSteps) Then End

Dim i As Long, j As Long, OP_LR As Long, OP_LC As Long
Dim OP As Worksheet
Dim x As Integer, PD_LR As Integer

PD_LR = PD.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
Set OP = Worksheets("Laminate Optimization")

If CurrentPly < UBound(LoopSteps) Then CurrentPly = CurrentPly + 1

**If CurrentPly = UBound(LoopSteps) Then
    For x = 5 To PD_LR
        PD.Range("D" & x) = OriginalAngles(x)
    Next x
    With Application
        .Run "Define_Locations"
        .Run "Effective_Laminate_Properties"
    End With
    End
End If**

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
**For i = 90 / LoopSteps(CurrentPly) To 0 Step -1
    PD.Range("D" & 3 + 2 * CurrentPly) = i * LoopSteps(CurrentPly)
    PD.Range("D" & 4 + 2 * CurrentPly) = -i * LoopSteps(CurrentPly)**
    With Application
        .Run "Define_Locations"
        .Run "Effective_Laminate_Properties"
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
    OP_LR = OP.Range("F" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
    OP_LC = 5
    For j = 5 To PD.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row Step 2
        OP.Cells(OP_LR + 1, OP_LC + 1) = PD.Range("D" & j)
        OP.Cells(OP_LR + 1, OP_LC + 1).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        OP_LC = OP_LC + 1
    Next j
    'OP.Cells(OP_LR + 1, UBound(LoopSteps) + 6) = ELP.Range("N3").Value
    'OP.Cells(OP_LR + 1, UBound(LoopSteps) + 7) = ELP.Range("N5").Value
    'OP.Cells(OP_LR + 1, UBound(LoopSteps) + 8) = ELP.Range("N6").Value
    'OP.Range(OP.Cells(OP_LR + 1, UBound(LoopSteps) + 6), OP.Cells(OP_LR + 1, UBound(LoopSteps) + 8)).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    'OP.Range(OP.Cells(OP_LR + 1, UBound(LoopSteps) + 6), OP.Cells(OP_LR + 1, UBound(LoopSteps) + 8)).NumberFormat = "#,##0.00"
Next i

**Call NestedLoop(PD, ELP, Permutations, CurrentPly, LoopSteps, OriginalAngles)**

Exit Function
ERROR_HANDLING:
    MsgBox "Error encountered in " & SubName & ": exiting function." _
    & vbNewLine _
    & vbNewLine & "Error description: " & Err.Description _
    & vbNewLine & "Error number: " & Err.Number, vbCritical, Title:="Error!"
    End

End Function
```

Comment: There's not really a lot to go off without seeing the actual code...

Comment: I've updated my original post.

Comment: It would be helpful to explain the output that you want shown in Excel.  You've listed the number of iterations, but not the output.  Also, one problem that you are likely to be having is that you have labeled this a function, but it doesn't return anything.  This is really a subroutine, not a function (or you need it to return something).  The way that you have tried to use recursion is essentially just another loop, so it seems that you'd be better off creating an outer loop in the whole procedure than using recursion.

Comment: The output is the "function" writing the values to two worksheets. Yes, it should be rewritten as a subroutine. I want this to be a dynamic nested loop, but am not familiar with how. Like I said, this is my first attempt at a self-taught recursion. :'(

Answer (score 0):

This will do the same thing it appears you are trying to do with recursion, instead using a loop, although I can't really visualize what you're trying to do.

```
Sub NestedLoop(PD As Worksheet, ELP As Worksheet, Permutations As Long, CurrentPly As Integer, LoopSteps() As Long, OriginalAngles() As Integer) 

    On Error GoTo ERROR_HANDLING
    Dim SubName As String
    SubName = "NestedLoop()"
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, OP_LR As Long, OP_LC As Long
    Dim OP As Worksheet
    Dim x As Integer, PD_LR As Integer
    Set OP = Worksheets("Laminate Optimization")

    Do While CurrentPly < UBound(LoopSteps)
         PD_LR = PD.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row

         Application.ScreenUpdating = False
         For i = 90 / LoopSteps(CurrentPly) To 0 Step -1
              PD.Range("D" & 3 + 2 * CurrentPly) = i * LoopSteps(CurrentPly)
              PD.Range("D" & 4 + 2 * CurrentPly) = -i * LoopSteps(CurrentPly)
              With Application
                   .Run "Define_Locations"
                   .Run "Effective_Laminate_Properties"
                   .ScreenUpdating = True
              End With
              OP_LR = OP.Range("F" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
              OP_LC = 5
              For j = 5 To PD.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row Step 2
                   OP.Cells(OP_LR + 1, OP_LC + 1) = PD.Range("D" & j)
                   OP.Cells(OP_LR + 1, OP_LC + 1).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                   OP_LC = OP_LC + 1
              Next j
              'OP.Cells(OP_LR + 1, UBound(LoopSteps) + 6) = ELP.Range("N3").Value
              'OP.Cells(OP_LR + 1, UBound(LoopSteps) + 7) = ELP.Range("N5").Value
              'OP.Cells(OP_LR + 1, UBound(LoopSteps) + 8) = ELP.Range("N6").Value
              'OP.Range(OP.Cells(OP_LR + 1, UBound(LoopSteps) + 6), OP.Cells(OP_LR + 1, UBound(LoopSteps) + 8)).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
              'OP.Range(OP.Cells(OP_LR + 1, UBound(LoopSteps) + 6), OP.Cells(OP_LR + 1, UBound(LoopSteps) + 8)).NumberFormat = "#,##0.00"
         Next i

        CurrentPly = CurrentPly + 1

     Loop
     'Upon Exiting loop, CurrentPly = UBound(LoopSteps)
     PD_LR = PD.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
     For x = 5 To PD_LR
         PD.Range("D" & x) = OriginalAngles(x)
     Next x
     With Application
        .Run "Define_Locations"
        .Run "Effective_Laminate_Properties"
     End With

    Exit Sub
ERROR_HANDLING:
    MsgBox "Error encountered in " & SubName & ": exiting function." _
    & vbNewLine _
    & vbNewLine & "Error description: " & Err.Description _
    & vbNewLine & "Error number: " & Err.Number, vbCritical, Title:="Error!"
    End

 End Sub
```